# como se puede obtener el codigo de error nativo de una excepcion en .net

Tags: c#

Como es sabido una misma excepcion se puede detonar de multiples maneras, un ejemplo de esto IOException que se inicia cuando un hay un timeout NetworkStream o cuando el host de un TcpClient se desconecta.
Lo que necesito es una manera de obtener el codigo de error de cada uno  de estos escenarios para poder actuar de la manera correcta.
Saludos

Comment: Has probado mirando la [InnerException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Como bien has dicho, hay varios tipos de excepciones dependiendo de cómo se originan, puedes tener una IOException, SqlException...

Algunas excepciones si que tienen un número que las identifica que se puede obtener a través de sus propiedad number.
Un ejemplo de estas es la SqlException que tiene una propiedad llamada Number.

Otras excepciones como InvalidOperationException no tiene la propiedad Number, puedes acceder a su propiedad Message para ver la explicación de la excepción.

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te refieres a la propiedad Message de la clase Exception:

```
try{

//código donde puede saltar una excepción 

catch (Exception e){
   string error =  e.Message;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5whzhsd2(v=vs.110).aspx